# FTP script called through SQR not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, winscp, sqr

In my SQR program, I am using call system USING

```
$ftpCommand #sendStatus WAIT
```

to grab a file from a FTP server. The `$ftpCommand` is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c E:\PS\psoft\dev\sqr_custom\ftp_from.bat
```

The `ftp_from.bat` contains one line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WINSCP.EXE" /console /script=\\servername\ps\psoft\dev\sqr_custom\cust_download.txt
```

The `cust_download.txt` is as following:

```
option batch on
option confirm off
open ftpservername
lcd localdirectoryname
option transfer ascii
echo 11111
get thefile.csv
close
exit
```

But the SQR errored out. I added `echo` to the `cust_download.txt` file, but can not see the echoed statement in SQR .out file.

So my question is why the FTP process does not work? And how to see my echoed message in the windows script?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ftp_from.bat` to:

```
set LOG=C:\some_writtable_folder\winscp.log
echo Before WinSCP > %LOG%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script=\\servername\ps\psoft\dev\sqr_custom\cust_download.txt" >> %LOG%
echo After WinSCP >> %LOG%
```

Note the [`WinSCP.com` instead of `WinSCP.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables).

And inspect the `winscp.log` file.

If it does not help, share the log file with us (edit your question).